# How to build a concatenate string in Alphabetical order?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, concatenation

I'm working with traveling axis and I have two databases:

The first has the origin and destination cities(let's say city A and city B). So I'm using *concat* to build an axis like CityA<>CityB. I can happen to be CityB<>CityA as well.

In the second database, I have a list with all axis and some trip information (such as distance, lat and long, and so on). But all of these axes are in alphabetical order.

What I'd like to do is treat data in DB1 to build the axes string in alphabetical order so I can properly join with DB2.

Can you help me with that??

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output.

Comment: we will be able to help you if you [Provide us with Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! please do!